# How do I test for difference in means of two exponentially distributed samples, when all I have is mean, standard deviation, and sample size?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, exponential-distribution

I have two samples, and in each sample I measured fluorescence intensity from 10k cells. Unfortunately the instrument doesn't return raw data, just histograms and summary statistics (mean, st.d., and sample size). From the histograms, the data looks roughly exponentially distributed. I want to test for a difference in means using only the histograms, means, st.ds, and sample sizes.

Option 1: If the data was roughly normal, I'd plug the summary stats into a t-test, e.g. [tsum.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PASWR/versions/1.1/topics/tsum.test). Unfortunately the data looks quite skewed, so I don't think that's appropriate:
[image]

Option 2: I also tried log-transforming the summary statistics, but unfortunately I'm not sure how to calculate `sd(logx)` from `sd(x)`.

What's the best way forward?

Comment: Do you have the sample sizes?

Comment: Yes, I have the sample sizes. Just edited the question to say so.

Comment: Honestly, a t-test is probably going to get you the right answer 80% of the time and take only 10% of the effort of finding the correct test—and if it's one you can use with just summary statistics. The general linear model is pretty robust.

Comment: "Roughly exponentially distributed" might be a misleading characterization.  The relatively large SD indicates a tendency to exhibit high outliers--precisely the kind of behavior that can produce misleading t-test p-values. Another potential problem is that if this histogram summarizes a spectrum, it might be combining strongly correlated values. If you don't account for that, any differences will seem more significant than they really are. Thus, the first step in a good way forward is to explain what these data actually measure.

Comment: Thanks @JarleTufto. Yes, that link answers my question. Marking this as a duplicate question.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the caveats. What do you mean by "summarizes a spectrum"?

Comment: Many "instruments" make multiple measurements, such as counts of radiation at various frequency ranges (which is the classic spectrum).

Comment: @whuber Thanks so much. Each data point is a fluorescence intensity from an individual cell, so I believe they're independent. I'll add this to the question in case it's useful.

Comment: If these are cells of a sensor, ordinarily they are strongly positively correlated.  For instance, if a pure point source is detected, how many cells will pick it up?  If more than one, then you have positive correlation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126969/discussion-between-r-greg-stacey-and-whuber).